# How do I write this in a single line?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, null, conditional-statements

I’m using Rails 4.2.5.  If I have this all by itself

```
urls_hash[provider.capitalize]
```

I get the error, “undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass”.  How do I write the above such that if the hash is empty, nothing is output, otherwise the given part of the hash is output?

Comment: What do you want to achieve

Comment: It should be urls_hash["provider"].capitalize capitalize method should called on the value that is returned by the hash i.e. on urls_hash["provider"]

Comment: That depends, perhaps the hash keys are uppercase providers?

Comment: yes you are right @LucasNelson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Ruby 2.3+, you can use the safe navigation operator to avoid the ternary check:

```
urls_hash&.fetch(provider.capitalize, nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

*([Lucas Nelson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35882349/1157242) is useful, but this also works if you are using Rails with Ruby 2.2 or less.)*

The hash is not **empty** (`{}`), it is **missing entirely** (`nil`). Based on your tags I assume you're using Rails, in which case you can do this:

```
url_hash.try(:[], provider.capitalize)
```

`#try` is essentially the same as `#send`, but `nil.try` returns `nil`. So you can chain a default value onto the above call using the `||` operator:

```
url_hash.try(:[], provider.capitalize) || 'Provider not specified'
```

Comment: Quite right. The result is the same. I'm tempted to say I prefer this way of doing it since it avoids the slightly oddball use of `fetch` with a nil param in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
urls_hash.blank? ? "" : urls_hash[provider.capitalize]
```

or

```
urls_hash[provider].capitalize
```

the second option will uppercase the content of the `urls_hash[provider]`

Comment: `urls_hash` is `nil`, not `{}`, and still won't respond to `[]`.

Comment: then use this `urls_hash.blank? ? "" : urls_hash[provider].capitalize`

Answer (score -1):

You can try this :

```
urls_hash[provider].capitalize if urls_hash.has_key? "provider"
```

Comment: `urls_hash` is `nil`, not `{}`, and won't respond to `has_key?` either.